# Problems with using "struct" in plain c

Tags: c, struct

I've got some problem here with struct. I have create a struct and a function to try to understand how the tree data structure works.Now the problem is that when I try to compile the following code with the command `gcc test.c -o test`, the compiler always return the error message `error： expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token`, please give me some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct BiTNode
{
    int data;
    struct BiTNode *lchild, *rchild;
}BiTNode, *BiTree;

void createTree(BiTree &T)
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == -1)
    {
        T = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        T = (BiTNode *)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
        T->data = i;
        createTree(T->lchild);
        createTree(T->rchild);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    BiTNode* root = NULL;
    createTree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, `BiTNode` in `typedef struct BiTNode` is redundant.

Comment: Do you expect `root` to be bon NULL after the `createTree(root);` statement ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, actually it is not redundant. If you paste the code in and compile (after fixing the declaration as @Ashalynd and @Elliott suggest) then the explicit `BiTNode` in the `typedef struct BiTNode` prevents the following compiler warning on the two lines: `createTree(T->lchild); createTree(T->rchild);` : `warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'struct BiTNode *' to parameter of type 'BiTree'`.  At least that's what my compiler tells me. Give it a try.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve actually ?

Comment: @DarrenStone Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct signature is:

```
void createTree(BiTree T)
```

and not:

```
void createTree(BiTree &T)
```

If fact, you can't use & in C function signatures. The way you did it would be valid in C++, that supports references. C does not do that.

You can use a pointer (e.g. `createTree(BiTNode* T)` ) in the signature, though, but in your case it's not needed, because you have already specified that BiTree is a pointer to BiTNode.

Important update: this change will make your function compile, but in order for it to work, you also need to make sure that you can actually use the pointer created inside that function. There are two ways to do that:

1) Return the new pointer as a result:

```
BiTree createTree()
{
    BiTree T;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == -1)
    {
        T = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        T = (BiTNode *)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
        T->data = i;
        T->lchild = createTree();
        T->rchild = createTree();
    }
    return T;
}

int main(void)
{
    BiTNode* root = NULL;
    root = createTree();
    return 0;
}
```

2) Give a pointer to BiTree as function argument (perhaps that was what you were meaning to do with the reference).

```
void createTree(BiTree *T)
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if(i == -1)
    {
        *T = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        *T = (BiTNode *)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
        (*T)->data = i;
        createTree(&(*T)->lchild);
        createTree(&(*T)->rchild);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    BiTNode* root = NULL;
    createTree(&root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, C only has pointers. It does not support references.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: @Ashalynd : Shouldn't the signature be `void createTree(BiTree *T)` ??

Comment: No, because from the code it seems that T is treated as a pointer to BiTNode, and not as a pointer to BiTree.

Comment: @Ashalynd : with your solution `root` will be NULL after the call to `createTree` and the call to `createTree` would be pointless. And also after `createTree(T->lchild)`, `T->lchild` would be unchanged.

Comment: Well, if you mean making it not only compile but also work, you are right. Will change my answer.

Comment: @Ashalynd : Obviously the program should also work and not only compile. But actually I'm not sure what the OP is trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to give reference to BiTree because in C++ it would have been done that way.

Answer (score 1):

Your function

```
 void createTree(BiTree &T)
```

should be

```
void createTree(BiTree *T)
```

or

```
void createTree(BiTree T)
```

You can't pass by reference with that C++ syntax in plain C.